# Determine whether each of these functions is a bijection from R to R

Tags: functions

> Determine whether each of these functions is a bijection from R to R.

I have a few questions in my text book asking me that. An example of one of them is:

$f(x) = −3x + 4$

From my understanding a bijection is a one-to-one function. With this in mind, how exactly can I determine if an equation like the one above is a bijection or not from R to R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is quite simple, so I respond it in a more guiding fashion:

When determining whether a function is bijective (or, a bijection), one should check if it is **one-to-one** (or, injective) **AND** **onto** (or, surjective).

Is it one to one? Yes. How so? A natural question to ask is whether two different elements are mapped to a same element? In fact, this is to check the definition of one-to-one!

Let us consider if there exist two such elements. Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $-3x + 4 = -3y + 4$, which implies $x = y$. So here we've get an implication: $"f(x) = f(y)" \;\Rightarrow\; "x = y" .$

So we've known that there are no two such elements unless they are the same! Hence the function is one-to-one.

For the *onto-ness*, we check if all elements in the codomain, namely $\mathbb{R}$, are all been mapped. We start the argument:

For each y $\in \mathbb{R}$, is there an x $\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x) = y$ ? Definitely yes! Since we can take $x = (y-4)/(-3)$ to make $f(x) = (-3)*(y-4)/(-3) + 4 = y $.

Comment: How did you figure out what to make $x$ equal when checking the the "onto-ness". You got $x = (y-4)/(-3)$ but I don't see how you came up with this?

Comment: We start from "pretending" the solution $x$ for $f(x) = y$ exists. Then this $x$ should satisfy $-3x + 4 = y \Rightarrow -3x = y - 4 \Rightarrow x = (y-4)/(-3)$.

Comment: Notice that this hasn't done the proof. We shall at last examine if that $x$ is really a solution. After all, we've been pretending as it exists. However, from the last implication, all we could know is: "If a solution $x$ does exist, it should be in the form $x = (y-4)/(-3)$."

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks, this solves it!

Answer (score 2):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is a **bijection** if it is *injective* (one-to-one) and *surjective* (onto).

We say $f$ is **injective** if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. We say $f$ is **surjective** if for every $y\in Y$ there exists an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Now, we are given $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=-3\,x+4$.

To see that $f$ is injective, suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $-3\,x+4=-3\,y+4$ so that $-3\,x=-3\,y$. It follows that $x=y$. Hence $f$ is injective.

To see that $f$ is surjective, suppose $y\in\Bbb R$. Can you find an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=y$?

Comment: Wow this was a very informative answer, it is very helpful! For the very last sentence regarding $f(x) = y$. Can't $y$ be any real value? And $x$ can be any real value, so wouldn't that mean that basically any number would work for this?

Comment: For example if I say $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ then do $f(1) = 1$, this proves there is an X that is a real value that is equal to $y$. Would this be correct?

Comment: @Fogest You want a formula for how to find the right $x$ so that $f(x)=y$. For example, consider $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^+$ given by $g(x)=e^x$. If $y\in\Bbb R^+$, then let $x=\ln(y)$. This gives $g(x)=g(\ln(y))=e^{\ln(y)}=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show bijection which is worth mentioning is that a function $f:A\to B$ is bijective if and only if it has an inverse $f^{-1}:B\to A$.  In your example, setting $x=-3y+4$ gives $y=-\frac13x+\frac43$. So,
$$f^{-1}(x)=-\frac13x+\frac43.$$

Hence, your function is injective.